# Como puedo guardar una ruta seleccionada por el usuario en un archivo de texto en python y tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Me gustaria guardar la ruta seleccionada por el usuario en un archivo txt , pero al ejecutar no me marca ningun error, mas el archivo de texto no tiene la ruta.

```
from tkinter import filedialog,Entry,Button,Tk
import os

class App:

    def guardaRutaTxt (self,nuevaRuta):
        f = open("Ruta.txt","w")
        f.write(nuevaRuta)
        f.close

    def ingresaRuta (self):
        ruta = filedialog.askdirectory()
        if ruta != "":
            os.chdir(ruta)
        nuevaRuta = os.getcwd()
        self.guardaRutaTxt(nuevaRuta)
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.Ventana = Tk()
        Button(self.Ventana,text="Escribir",command=self.ingresaRuta).place(x=0,y=0)
        self.Ventana.mainloop()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
```

Comment: Funciona correctamente, genera el archivo en la ruta que hayas seleccionado. Dónde estás buscando el archivo?

Comment: Te faltan los parentesis en f.close (funcion guardaRutaTxt )

Comment: El archivo lo genera en la misma carpeta del proyecto, pero no cuenta con la ruta escrita en el

Comment: @Eduardo mi comentario te sirvió?

Answer (score 0):

Encontre el problema y es que tengo que especificar la ruta del archivo txt antes de que el usuario ingrese la ruta que va a escribir, Ademas de crear el archivo txt antes.

```
from tkinter import filedialog,Entry,Button,Tk
import os

class App:

    def guardaRutaTxt (self,nuevaRuta,archivo):
        f = open(archivo,"w")
        f.write(nuevaRuta)
        f.close()

    def ingresaRuta (self):
        archivo = os.path.abspath("Ruta.txt")
        ruta = filedialog.askdirectory()
        if ruta != "":
            os.chdir(ruta)
        nuevaRuta = os.getcwd()
        self.guardaRutaTxt(nuevaRuta,archivo)
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.Ventana = Tk()
        Button(self.Ventana,text="Escribir",command=self.ingresaRuta).place(x=0,y=0)
        self.Ventana.mainloop()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
```

El problema era que el archivo txt lo creaba en la ruta que seleccionaba el usuario y no en el proyecto.